# Continuous Wireless data packet streaming in OpenWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, openwrt

I am using OpenWRT 15.05 on a Linksys 1900ACS router to broadcast continuous data stream via UDP (open to other alternatives) (a song). The router is running 100s of devices, currently by running a multicast (and in future by a plain broadcast of data from the router and all receiver devices sniffing the data packets).

Even though I send the packet to the router at exactly regular intervals, the devices receive it after a random amount of delay (which varies in seconds, not milliseconds) because of some buffering happening in the router. How can I configure the router in a mode to keep transmitting data as it receives it from the computer without any buffering (or CSMA/CA etc), or at least with a constant delay across all packets.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is tricky on 802.11, so you probably won't like these answers.

On the clients, set their Listen Interval to 1. The Listen Interval controls how many beacon periods a client in power-save mode keeps its radio reciever off (asleep) before waking it up to see if the AP has queued up any traffic for it. If you want clients to receive traffic in a timely manner, you have to keep them awake more of the time. So there's a battery life tradeoff. If you can't set the Listen Interval on a given client, turn off power save mode all together on that client.

On the AP, set the DTIM interval to 1. The DTIM Interval controls how many beacon intervals go by before the AP tries to send out multicast packets. Setting it to 1 means the AP will send out multicasts right after every beacon, which is by default every 102.4 ms (about every 1/10th of a second). So a DTIM Interval of 1 would allow mean multicasts are delayed by only 51ms on average. If you don't even want that much, then either disable power save mode on all your clients (so multicasts can always be sent out the moment they come in), or set your Beacon Interval to something smaller than the 102.4ms default most APs use. If your AP doesn't let you set the DTIM Interval or the Beacon Interval, then you'll have to just disable power save mode on all your clients.

If the problem is that the multicasts aren't being received reliably, fixes include lowering the multicast rate (i.e. the PHY rate at which the AP transmits multicasts) and disabling wireless security. WPA2 and WPA require multicasts to be encrypted with a different key than unicasts, and some devices can be a bit buggy with how they deal with that multicast (group) key.

If the problem is that long queues of frame buffers are building up in your AP, that's called "bufferbloat", and the OpenWrt website has a good page about enabling FQ-CoDel to defeat bufferbloat.